# sed: display lines before a match

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

Using sed looking for the last lines before matching lines:

```
echo -e "aaa\nbbb\nccc\naaa\nccc\naaa\nbbb\nccc" | sed '/aaa/!d' | sed '$!d' #In which order and amount of aaa, bb, ccc, ..., nnn is optional
```

The example above works well. The second method:

```
echo -e "aaa\nbbb\nccc\naaa\nccc\naaa\nbbb\nccc" | sed -e '/aaa/!d' -e '$!d'
```

or:

```
echo -e "aaa\nbbb\nccc\naaa\nccc\naaa\nbbb\nccc" | sed -e '/aaa/!d;$!d'
```

The second method does not want me to work. The wikipedia someone wrote that sed can be combined. I do not want to work. What I'm doing wrong and I understand? How should properly look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/aaa/h;$!d;x' file
```

To catch the last match you must store it in the hold space then retrieve it at the end of the file.

Comment: Thank you. Is perfectly. I understand you do not know how yet. I take to be "man sed".

Comment: Sure @potong learned to sed.

Guides to help you understand sed:
man sed
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html
http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/sed1line.txt

Good tutoarial and a lot can be learned. You have to take care of the poor.

Answer (score 1):

What is the desired output?  The first command gives a single line `aaa`. The second and third commands give no output.  There's a solid reason for the discrepancy in the behaviour.

In the first command, you have:

```
sed '/aaa/!d' | sed '$!d'
```

The first `sed` here deletes each line that is not `aaa`.  The output (3 lines containing `aaa`) is then filtered so that only the last line is printed.

In the second and third commands (which are equivalent), you have:

```
sed -e '/aaa/!d' -e '$!d'
```

The first operand deletes each line that is not `aaa` and starts the next cycle.  The second operand deletes every remaining `aaa` because none of them is on the last line of input (the last line in the input is `ccc`, which has already been deleted by virtue of not being `aaa`).  So the output you see is exactly what you should expect.

If you want just one `aaa`, consider using:

```
grep '^aaa$' | uniq
```

Though that's a long-winded way of writing:

```
echo aaa
```

Presumably, though, this is a simplified version of the real situation (which is a good thing).

Answer (score 0):

$ in the address means the last line. It does not change even if the last line is not being printed because of a previous command. In the pipeline, though, only the printed lines get to the second invocation of sed, and $ again means the last line - now only from the lines printed by the previous sed invocation.

Comment: Thank you. A can be another way to catch the last line?